# how to close a port on CentOS 7 server?

Tags: centos, firewall, firewalld, port

I have opened the 3000 port of my CentOS 7 server with the following commands:

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=3000/tcp --permanent
firewall-cmd --reload
```

But now I want to closing them, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`firewall-cmd --zone=public --remove-port=3000/tcp --permanent`

should do the trick.

`man firewall-cmd` is always at your disposal.